# Resource directory specific to a region (not a locale)

Tags: android, android-resources

Is it possible to create an Android Resource Directory that is only specific to a region?

In Android, if you want to make a Resource Directory specific to a locale, you name it in the following manner `values-de` (German locale), and if you want it to be specific to a locale and region you name it like `values-de-rAT` (German locale with Austrian region). In my case, I do not care about the locale and only about the region, but the following `values-rAT` does not seem to be valid.

I know that I can get the region in code with `getLocales(resources.configuration).get(0).country` but I was wondering if there is a way to work with resource directories too.

Comment: `... if you want it to be specific to a locale and region you name it like values-de-rAT (German locale with Austrian region). In my case, I do not care about the locale and only about the region, but the following values-rAT does not seem to be valid. ...` You already answered yourself.

Comment: `values-de-rAT` (German locale with Austrian region) is what you need to use.

Comment: I think you did not properly read the post. I do NOT care about the locale, ONLY the region/country.

Comment: Well, it's actually **the same**. Since the provided resources in a **regionalized locale** folder will work **only** in the specified **region**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create resources for a country by using the country code qualifier: MCC or MNC. For example, `mcc310` is U.S. on any carrier

Here's the link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

[image]

Comment: It is not exactly what I needed, but I just read in the link that you posted that `You cannot specify a region alone.` so I think your proposed solution is the closest that one can get. Thank you!

Comment: For the sake of completeness I am posting a link with the list of MCCs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code